# Azure pipeline XCode build task times out on Running script '[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock'

Tags: xcode, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cocoapods, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am running a Xcode clean build pipeline task in Azure devops

- task: Xcode@5

and it does get stuck when running the script bellow.

If I run it using the UAT scheme it does succeed the issue happens only using release build

```
▸ Running script '[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock'
##[debug]Re-evaluate condition on job cancellation for step: 'Xcode Build'.
##[error]The operation was canceled.
##[debug]System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
```

Here is the task:

```
        - task: Xcode@5
        displayName: 'Xcode Build'
        continueOnError: ${{ parameters.CanContinue }}
        inputs:
          actions: 'clean build'
          ${{ if eq(variables['configuration'], 'DEBUG' ) }}:
            scheme: 'MyProject_UAT_Debug'
          ${{ if eq(variables['configuration'], 'UAT' ) }}:
            scheme: 'MyProject_UAT_Release'
          ${{ if eq(variables['configuration'], 'RELEASE' ) }}:
            scheme: 'MyProject_PROD_Release'
          sdk: '$(sdk)'
          configuration: $(configuration)
          xcWorkspacePath: 'MyProject.xcworkspace'
          xcodeVersion: 'default'
          packageApp: true
          signingOption: 'manual'
          provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
          signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
          exportPath: '$(agent.buildDirectory)/output/$(sdk)/$(configuration)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to run first on your machine the following command  (remove the derived data first) and see the full logs

`[command]/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release -workspace /Path/MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme MyProject_PROD clean build`

I've added the timeoutInMinutes: 0 in the yml file for now until I get a better solution